# Check if hangfire recurring job is already running

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have an web app that is leveraging Hangfire for background tasks and jobs.

I have a recurring job where 2 instances of this job cannot be executing at any one time. Lets say the job takes longer to execute.

I would like to check if the job is currently running, and if so, do not re run.

I have looked around and cannot find any information on this.

Comment: There's some guidance in the comments here: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html. Essentially, there's no *good* way, but there's a few potential workarounds.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for this. Yeah I didn't think there was an obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 14):

There are multiple places where parts of this are answered, but for me to get this working completely, I had to do TWO things:

1. Know the attributes
2. Put them on the Interface, not the implementation method

So if you are using interfaces (for example with dependency injection) to kick off the Hangfire job put these on the *Interface* definition

```
[DisableConcurrentExecution(10)]
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0, LogEvents = false, OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Delete)]
```

If you don't do the AutomaticRetry attribute this way, the default is that the job will get added to the Scheduled job list to run when the first one finishes.

This works the way I wanted it to:

Run the job every 5 minutes.  If during the next 5 minute interval, the previous job is still running, do not queue a new instance of it.

If you put these on the method that implements the interface, it does nothing.

Comment: I don't know if this changed since then, but I'm on hangfire 1.8.6 using MSSQL as background. I did this, but different behavior. The scheduled job will start in "processing" even though another one is blocking, but it wont begin executing the body of the method. I need a [SkipIfAlreadyRunning] attribute instead.

Answer (score 3):

We're using the job filters, specifically this one:
**MaximumConcurrentExecutions** - https://github.com/alastairtree/Hangfire.MaximumConcurrentExecutions
Which will prevent multiple instances of your job being fired up.

you can also look at **DisableConcurrentExecution**  -
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/disableconcurentexecution-does-not-appear-to-work/158.

They both serve a similar purpose, with the former allowing you to limit the maximum to a number > 1, whereas using the latter will not allow any concurrent processing for the Job.

If, however, you have multiple different jobs being processed in the same function, you'll need to update the filter to check the specific job type you want to throttle.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is valid for Hangfire.Core `1.7.30.0`

It has the following interface

```
// Assembly Hangfire.Core, Version=1.7.30.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
namespace Hangfire.Storage
{
    public interface IMonitoringApi
    {
        ...
        JobList<EnqueuedJobDto> EnqueuedJobs(string queue, int from, int perPage);
        JobList<FetchedJobDto> FetchedJobs(string queue, int from, int perPage);
        JobList<ProcessingJobDto> ProcessingJobs(int from, int count);
        JobList<ScheduledJobDto> ScheduledJobs(int from, int count);
        JobList<SucceededJobDto> SucceededJobs(int from, int count);
        JobList<FailedJobDto> FailedJobs(int from, int count);
        JobList<DeletedJobDto> DeletedJobs(int from, int count);
        ...
    }
}
```

Using it as follows:

```
private readonly IMonitoringApi _api;
public object_constructor(Hangfire.JobStorage jobStorage)
{
    _api = jobStorage.GetMonitoringApi();
}

public List<dynamic> GetProcessingJobs(int? from = null, int? count = null)
{
    var list = _api.ProcessingJobs(from ?? 0, count ?? int.MaxValue);
    if (list == null) return new List<dynamic>();
    var items = list.Where(kv => kv.Value.Job != null)
         .Select(kv => new {
            kv.Key,
            kv.Value.Job.Method.Name,
            kv.Value.InProcessingState,
            kv.Value.ServerId,
            StartedAt = kv.Value.StartedAt, // UTC
            Duration = DateTime.UtcNow - kv.Value.StartedAt,
            Args = string.Join(",", kv.Value.Job?.Args.Select(e => e ?? "null"))
        })
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.StartedAt)
        .Cast<dynamic>()
        .ToList();
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone thought of an even simpler solution?  How about a sql table that has among other fields, a bit field to indicate "IsProcessing".  The job would check this at the very beginning.  If true, then exit.  once finished, set it to false.
Thoughts?

Comment: I wish, at this point I think their slogan should be "hangfire, making background jobs hard" -_-